# How to create API POST Request via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, api, http

I am trying to send data from an excel sheet to my marketplace management system using their api calls. I seem to not be getting the part of my code down, where the call actually goes through. I have every other part down, except for this part.

I have tried to do just the URL, change the MSXML reference tool, and take away all other code and just run the POST code, but none of that seems to effect it.

```
Sub newfile()     
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 URL = "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Orders(876662)/Export? 
 access_token=xxxxx"
 objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 objHTTP.send
End Sub
```

The results should be that when I pull in data from the marketplace management system, items that I mark as exported with this post request, should not appear unless I call for them directly.

Comment: If you have a reference to MSXML, then you can declare `objHTTP As ServerXMLHTTP` and get intellisense for its member calls and explore its members in the object browser (F2)... and you can `New` it up instead of hitting the Windows registry to locate the type with a progID string.

Comment: `objHTTP.send` is not sending any data. is it expecting you to pass a particular data set? If so, what is expecting you to pass? XML? JSON? form? Each api has it's own unique setup and requirements to send/receive data. Maybe the marketplace api as some api documentation that can help you

Comment: https://developer.channeladvisor.com/rest-api-core-concepts/anatomy-of-a-request   ,   https://developer.channeladvisor.com/working-with-orders

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching the file to use an xmlhttp instead of objhttp. By changing all of those and adding in `Dim xmlhttp As ServerXMLHTTP` it now sends the appropriate data to the API.